# listen to web socket from switching protocols url

Tags: python, websocket

I have the following connection:

```
GET /.ws?ns=XXXXX&v=5&ls=XXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: firebaseio.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XXXXXXXXXX
```

And then a `101 Switching Protocols` message is shown:

```
TTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 11:58:49 GMT
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: XXXXXXXXX
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
```

I'd like to listen to the websocket but all examples requires a `ws://` connection where as here the connection is made from a URL.

Comment: You might be able to start straight off with a websocket communication simply by changing the beginning of the URL. Failing that, you might be able to open the connection, send the get request and then connect the open connection to your websocket library.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: https://github.com/ilkerkesen/tornado-websocket-client-example/blob/master/client.py

just replace the url scheme:

```
    http:// -> ws://  
    https:// -> wss://
```